# QTableView signal or event for "row height changed"

Tags: qt, qt4, pyqt

I' m looking for an Event or Signal like *"row height changed*" that is called if the user changes the height of a row in my QTableView. I want to use this signal to resize all other rows in the QTableView to the new height. I didn' t find such an Event or Signal so I reckon there must be some kind of handy workaround.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Row resizing is performed by the vertical QHeaderView. The object emmiting it is QTableView::verticalHeader()

the signal you are interested in is

```
void QHeaderView::sectionResized ( int logicalIndex, int oldSize, int newSize )
```

This signal is emitted when a section is resized. The section's logical number is specified by logicalIndex, the old size by oldSize, and the new size by newSize.

Answer (score 1):

Use `QHeaderView` (You can get an instance by calling `QTableView::horizontalHeader()`/`QTableView::verticalHeader()` ) and connect to `geometriesChanged()` or `sectionResized()`

Answer (score 0):

The solution with `QHeaderView` and `sectionResized` works very well for me. So for resizing all
rows to the same height as the edited row I use this code now:

```
class MyWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        #Do some other init things

        self.myTable.verticalHeader().sectionResized.connect(
            self.row_resized)

    def row_resized(self, index, old_size, new_size):
        for i in range(self.myTable.verticalHeader().count()):
            self.myTable.setRowHeight(i, new_size)
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to save data after a section was resized, but found `sectionResized` fired a signal continuously while adjusting, rather than once at the end.
The simplest solution I could think of was to subclass the `QHeaderView`.

```
class CustomHeader(QtWidgets.QHeaderView):
    """
    Custom header class to return when a section has been resized
    Only after mouse released, opposed to continuously while resizing
    """
    on_section_resized = QtCore.Signal(int)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomHeader, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._has_resized = False
        self._index = 0

        self.sectionResized.connect(self.section_resized)

    def section_resized(self, index, old_size, new_size):
        self._has_resized = True
        self._index = index

        return

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        super(CustomHeader, self).mouseReleaseEvent(event)

        if self._has_resized:
            self._has_resized = False
            self.on_section_resized.emit(self._index)

        return
```

In my main class I assigned the header to the table widget:

```
self.table_widget.setVerticalHeader(CustomHeader(QtCore.Qt.Vertical, self.table_widget))
```

Then connected the custom signal to my function within the original class:

```
self.table_widget.verticalHeader().on_section_resized.connect(self.save_section_height)
```

Part of the Save function:

```
def save_section_height(self, row):
    """
    Updates the edited row's section height

    :param row: int, row that has been changed

    :return: None
    """

    new_section_height = self.table_widget.verticalHeader().sectionSize(row)
```

I expect some things could be optimised better, but this at least fires one save signal opposed to ten plus, or something!